# Использование звёздочки в стилях

Tags: css

Я в исходниках одного сайта нашел `*a`. Что это значит? Что значит сама звездочка, `*`?

Comment: Я почти уверен, что это просто опечатка. Есть селектор `*`, означающий "выбрать все тэги" (универсальный селектор). Есть селектор `a`, означающий "выбрать все тэги `a`". А `*a` — такого нет.

Comment: Скиньте ссылку на W3C validator, если считаете что это  допустимо.

Comment: ну я так не писал код, просто увидел в исходниках и сам хочу понять почему он так написан

Comment: Я вам говорю, что это опечатка. Вы спорите, что это работает. Говорю: провалидируйте CSS. Вы это сделали?

Comment: Я уже понял, что это не вы писали.

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, браузеры в которых этот селектор работает.

Comment: В справочнике https://webref.ru/css ты найдешь все, что тебе надо

Comment: а чем вам помог ответ Developer?

Answer (score 4):

Я почти уверен, что это просто опечатка.
Есть селектор `*`, означающий "выбрать все тэги" (универсальный селектор).
Есть селектор `a`, означающий "выбрать все тэги a".
А `*a` — такого нет.

Comment: я получил от заказчика исходный код и там есть такое

Comment: @Max Без проблем. Я ответил на ваш вопрос?

Comment: ну тогда, что значит этот код *a {
 transition: color 0.2s, background-color 0.2s;
 -moz-transition: color 0.2s, background-color 0.2s;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.2s, background-color 0.2s;
 -o-transition: color 0.2s, background-color 0.2s;
}

Comment: Отлично, 1. А он работает? 2. Даже если он работает, это не значит, что это валидный, так как браузеры по разному работают с опечатками в HTML\CSS.

Comment: ну да. у сайта нет ни одной ошибки

Comment: Отлично, сделайте **запускаемый** пример и добавьте его в вопрос.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov я сделал [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2q4prLf3/). Судя по тестам, `*a` просто игнорируется: не воспринимается ни как `*`, ни как `a`.

Comment: @Max [W3c](https://validator.w3.org/check) выдал ошибку по данному коду. Скорее всего так был какой-то один элемент.

Answer (score 0):

В целом, вам стоит заглянуть [сюда](http://htmlbook.ru/css).

Вот код из примера по вашему вопросу, для общего понимания вопроса:

```css
[href*="htmlbook"] { 
  background: yellow; /* Желтый цвет фона */
}
```

```html
<p><a href="http://www.htmlbook.ru/html/">Теги HTML</a> | 
<a href="http://stepbystep.htmlbook.ru">Шаг за шагом</a> | 
<a href="http://webimg.ru">Графика для Веб</a></p>
```

И второй пример

```css
* { 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; /* Убираем отступы и поля для всех элементов */
   }
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diem 
  nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut lacreet dolore magna aliguam erat volutpat.</p>
```

Comment: И как ваш ответ соотносится к вопросу? Причём тут атрибуты, где вы увидели квадратные скобки в вопросе?

Comment: Вопрос про систему звездочек в целом. По двум примерам можно без труда понять, что звездочка означает любые элементы. Причем применимо это как ко всем стилям, так и отдельным элементам, определяя изменяемую часть и постоянную.

Comment: Хорошо, про звёздочку разобрались. А первая часть ответа `[href*="htmlbook"]`  к чему?

Comment: А это "Ответы на подобные вопросы вы без труда в течении 10 секунд сможете отыскать в сети." какую несёт информационную нагрузку? Намекнуть, что автор недалёк или просто ленив и мог бы за 10 секунд найти?

Comment: Неизвестно в каком контексте он нашел эту звездочку, поэтому и 2 примера. По поводу 10 секунд, это лишь намек на то, что автор вопроса мог бы быстрее отыскать ответ на вопрос через поиск, чем описывать его тут.

Comment: 1. И зачем этот намёк? Как какие выводы из него надо делать? 2. Там нигде не описывается селектор `*a`. А автор вопроса мог и не найти.

Comment: Это не намек, я так же как и он задаю вопросы. Ни на что не намекаю, лишь обращаю внимание, что информации на подобные вопросы очень много готовой и можно быстрее найти готовый ответ. Если селектор не описывается в справочнике, то, смело можно предположить, что кто-то допустил ошибку.

Comment: Я считаю этот фрагмент неконстуктивным и проявлением неуважения к автору вопроса, поэтому держите заслуженый минус.

Comment: Поступайте так, как считаете нужным.

Comment: Да я просто пытаюсь вам объяснить, что в ответе даже на элементарные вопросы нужно проявлять терпение. Если вам не нравится вопрос, то можете не отвечать. А ещё потенциально это могут читать много других людей. Если вы считаете нормальным, что они будут чувствовать себя дураками, то это прискорбно.

Comment: Чтоб вам спалось покрепче, это предложение я убрал. Надеюсь в этом предложении вы не усмотрите скрытого смысла и издевок!

Answer (score -2):

Это либо опечатка, либо костыль под какой-то конкретный браузер. Например, старые IE ели звёздочку перед именем css-свойства. Может и для тегов прокатывает - не знаю.

Comment: А можете привести примеры и указать какие именно браузеры имеются ввиду (старые — понятие относительное, желательно версию)? Я просто никогда не видел звёздочек перед именем свойств, поэтому любопытно.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, вроде IE7-. Самая классика `*zoom: 1`. http://stackoverflow.com/q/14927651/4928642

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, и вообще https://habrahabr.ru/post/125396/